# How to reference $(this) when using on()

Tags: this, jquery, jquery-on

I'm using `on()` to mimic `live()` and can't for the life of me figure out how to properly reference `$(this)` so it references the selector I passed in. Here's the code, `$(this)` returns `"body"` instead of `"select"`.

```
$("body").on("change", "select", function(e){
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/7RgVP/

Comment: well, it works with $(this) itself... !

Comment: I'm with @Musa. I've never seen `on` work the way you're saying it is. Can you reproduce this with a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Musa is correct. So the context I am using this in is a jquery plugin I'm writing. It's for an element that doesn't exist yet when the plugin is called. So `$this = $(e.target)` solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(e.currentTarget);
```

e is actually the event arguments for the event and that's what you want I beleive.

Comment: Haha, of course! I was thinking there was some "other" on() specific way.

Comment: Yeah the on implementation takes a bit of getting used to. It's much better and can be a lot more robust, but look out for rebinding of events if you're used to the old way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**event.target**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to the the source of event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uN7KB/)**

```
$("body").on("change", "select", function(e){
    console.log($(e.target));
});
```

Comment: Not the same as `this` in a jQuery event though, the proper property is `.currentTarget`

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. See http://jsfiddle.net/S9fbY/. In some situations it is accidentally same as `this` though.

Comment: @Esailija, he wants to get select and that will be given by e.target and not by e.currentTarget?

Comment: as far as I can see he wanted another way to use `this` inside event handler, which is done with `e.currentTarget`. However, his problem is made up and he can just use `this` though.

Comment: I thought he need select as he states "Here's the code, $(this) returns "body" instead of "select"", Anyhow thanks @Esailija for your time and guidance.

Comment: He was looking for the select tag, not the selected item - ie the actual dropdown element from the dom. This is e.currentTarget to return the dom object that fired the event.

Comment: @Gats Look at the last comment by Patrick Robert Shea O'Connor below his Question.